# Gif loader does not hides out after subscribing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate SendGrid subscription widget into my site (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-subscription-widget). The sample code provided by the company is partially working. As I hit the sign up button the loader shows up and displays a success message, but the gif loader do not hides out even after receiving the message. I want the loader stops showing as soon as the process completes. I have pasted the js code snippet. I cannot detect the problem. It might be due to my marginal js knowledge.

```
    $(".sendgrid-subscription-widget").on("sent", function () {
    $(this).addClass("loading")
           .append("<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif\" alt=\"Loading...\">");
    $(this).find("input[type=submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $(".sendgrid-subscription-widget").on("success error", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("loading")
        $(this).find("img").remove();
        $(this).find("input[type=submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

HTML markup

```
<div class="sendgrid-subscription-widget" data-token="1M5Z249eGJzJ34D5llN3s2KkzNImaU9gZp8ImuJSw1pmhsJvugAYeWJXhtK1aWLO" data-executed="true">
    <form>
        <div class="response"></div>
        <label>
            <span>Email</span>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="you@example.com" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif" alt="Loading...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Js to this :

```
$(".sendgrid-subscription-widget").on("sent", function () {
    $(this).addClass("loading")
           .append("<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif\" alt=\"Loading...\">");
    $(this).find("input[type=submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $(".sendgrid-subscription-widget").on("success error", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("loading")
        $(document).find(".loading img").remove();
        $(this).find("input[type=submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it: this code is now working ... js console helped me.

```
    $(".sendgrid-subscription-widget").on("sent", function () {
    $(this).addClass("loading")
           .append("<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif\" alt=\"Loading...\">");
    $(this).find("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");


    $(".sendgrid-subscription-widget").on("success error", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("loading")
        $(this).find("img").remove();
        $(this).find("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```